# Tube amplifier buzzing

Tags: amplifiers, amplification, vacuum-tube

I'm having some issues with buzzing coming the amplifier. When I turn the amp on I get a buzzing noise from the speaker. I've found that it's related to the TV in the next room, when this is turned off at the mains the buzzing goes away. So i'm assuming it's some sort of signal between the two

The amp has been serviced and is working fine, also when I try it upstairs it works fine. So the issue isn't with the amp, the buzzing also changes depending how close the amp is to the TV.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of this?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose having the TV off while you play isn't an option?

Comment: For the most part no, unfortunately. I live in a shared house so it's a little unfair to ask my housemates to turn the TV off while I have a play on the guitar.

I've tried to do a bit of research on like "Mains power conditioners" "Noise gate pedals" and other various bits but I'm finding it all a bit confusing.

Comment: Possibly try a different mains circuit. Or get a better screened lead from guitar to amp. Twin core and screened could do it. Or go wireless.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Unfortunately the issue is there whether the guitar is plugged in or not so I'm fairly sure this isn't the issue (Sorry this was left off the initial thread. I've tried the amp in all the downstairs sockets and the issue persists. It get louder the closer the amp gets to TV/virgin media box. 

It works fine in the upstairs sockets but these are my housemates bedrooms so it's not really a viable option. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Is it a CRT or digital flat screen? CRT sets are notorious for radiating electrical interference.

Comment: It's  flat screen, but its more than likely the media box as opposed to the TV itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyones interested I managed to find a reasonable solution to this (which didn't cost the earth)

Also just want to say thanks for all your suggestions. They all helped in some form or another to reduce the problem.

Basically a guy in Forsyths music shop in Manchester suggested getting one of these;

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tacima-6-Way-Mains-Conditioner-black/dp/B00UB0G4DQ/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1553342257&sr=1-1&keywords=tacima+6+way+mains+conditioner

I can still hear a bit of buzz but you wouldn't notice it unless you're looking for it. So I'll try and adding a Ferrite Choke to the AC power in the other room and this should hopefully help even more but the mains conditioner seems to have done the trick.

Thanks

Comment: Snap-on ferrites are used for the suppression of much higher frequencies than 50Hz mains hum. I would be quite surprised if any improvement were noticed over the very large inductor already present in the filter shown in your photo.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning it 90°, sometimes helps.
Alternatively, move the amp to the far end of the room, as far away as you can get it.

It's probably simple induction, so quite capable of passing through a wall, unless it's heavy brick or stone. It will fade with distance, like light or sound. If it is induction, no amount of power conditioning will help.

Also, check whether it's actually the amp itself, or the amp plus guitar/cable, & whether moving just yourself & instrument further away helps at all.

Comment: Thanks,

Unfortunately turning 90° didn't help. The amplifier is also as far away as I can get it.  It does seem like it's to do with your suggestion regarding distance so I'll see if I can find any other solutions.

Thanks very much.